# How to send iMessage on AppleScript?

Tags: python, applescript, imessage

I want to send an iMessage using AppleScript, and Python. Code is compiling, but no messages are being sent.

```
script = """tell application "Messages"
send "TEST TEXT" to buddy "1xxxxxxx" of service "E:xxx@gmail.com"

end tell"""

def script_run(script):
  applescript.run(script)

script_run(script)

script = """tell application "Messages"
send "TEST TEXT" to buddy "1xxxxxxx" of service "E:xxx@gmail.com"

end tell"""

def script_run(script):
  applescript.run(script)

script_run(script)
```

Comment: I don't know whether this will be a factor for you, but in case you aren't aware, you will only be able to send messages to existing conversations in _Messages_.  You cannot send an iMessage with AppleScript as a brand new conversation.